# Codeigniter Upload File Issue

Tags: codeigniter, upload

Hi this is my code:

```
$config['upload_path'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/licenta/application/images/products';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '2048';
        $x = $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        if (!$this->upload->do_upload()){
             //failed
        }else{
             //success
        }
```

This is: `$this->upload->do_upload()` always false. My form is correct I get the right data if I use `var_dump($_FILES);`. The path is:

```
C:/xampp/htdocs/licenta/application/images/products
```

I tried also this version /images/products/ or ./images/products/ or ../images/product/. None of them are working. I am using XAMPP. What else should be the problem? I check the others post and the documentation and for them are working, for me is not. Can someone help me? I am stuck :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the HTML field name attribute in **do_upload()** function:
See below code:

$this->upload->do_upload('**userfile**');

I hope it will work.

Comment: Its working , I don't understand why this is not mention in the doc. THx :)

Comment: @Chester It says it here http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html#the-controller